# Any alternatives for the word "deservability"?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

The word "deservability" officially doesn't exist in dictionary. But, we might come across few situations where you need to make sentences like this one.

> You deserve that job. But sometimes, capability is also required along with **deservability**.

I was discussing with my friend this morning who lost his job very recently and I had to say something like the above sentence but couldn't find the right words.

Are there any alternatives for the word "deservability" and if so, how to use those words in the situations like above?

Comment: **deservingness** *noun* 1. - the quality of being deserving (e.g., deserving assistance); "there were many children whose deservingness he recognized and rewarded" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deservingness

Comment: We could go for a more suitable synonym instead, according to context. Such as *merit*, *worthiness*.

Comment: It's the job that's deserved, so presumably the deservability would be a quality of the job, not the potential job-holder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word which you are looking for is **[deservedness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/deservedness)**.

Answer (score 3):

I think **worthy** or **worthiness** is the perfect substitution word you're looking for. It is used to indicate that someone has earned the value attributed them through their proven record or high quality of work and effort.

Miriam-Webster defines it as:
[worthy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worthy)

```
  : good and deserving respect, praise, or attention
  : having enough good qualities to be considered important, useful, etc.
```

> You deserve that job. But sometimes, capability is also required along with worthiness.

Comment: I apologize for forgetting to cite my definition source. Also I have edited my answer to explain why I think my suggestion fits the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine as is. I was an English major and there are some philosophical questions in regards to the English language in particular. In general there are two schools: it's only valid if it's in the dictionary, or it's valid if people use it and understand it. This can almost be defined as the Webster's vs American Heritage approach. The English language, especially American English, in my opinion is strong exactly because it allows such flexibility. Some other languages don't. At the end of the day I think any reasonable English speaker will understand exactly what you mean and agree with the spelling. I think deservability in particular is a very clear word choice because the combination of "deserve" and "ability" which is not expressed in any other alternative. Anyway, I hope that helps.